# postgresql - cannot modify default "postgres" user

Tags: django, postgresql, server, digital-ocean

How to change, alter, postgres default values for my project?

I have a django project which I try to deploy to digital ocean on an ubunto instance.

In psql I create a new user with new_password and grant it all privileges to the new_db.

Yet, these created entries are not connected to my project database. i.e. The values of the databases remain the default ones:
Name/User/Password=postgres

I note here the commands I run the Docean, ubuntu server:

Assunming a new_user created (i.e. none root) and all psql packages are installed.

1. sudo -u postgres psql
2. CREATE DATABASE new_db;
   #DATABASE created;
3. CREATE USER new_user WITH PASSWORD 'new_psw';
4. ALTER ROLE new_user SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
   ALTER ROLE new_user SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
   ALTER ROLE new_user SET timezone TO 'UTC';
5. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE new_db TO new_user;

Quitting postgres, I my database value on my shell:
The values remain the default ones:

```
DATABASES {‘default’: {‘ENGINE’: ‘django.db.backends.postgresql’, ‘NAME’: ‘postgres’, ‘USER’: ‘postgres’, ‘PASSWORD’: ‘postgres’, ‘HOST’: ‘localhost’, ‘PORT’: 5432, ‘ATOMIC_REQUESTS’: False, ‘AUTOCOMMIT’: True, ‘CONN_MAX_AGE’: 0, ‘CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS’: False, ‘OPTIONS’: {}, ‘TIME_ZONE’: None, ‘TEST’: {‘CHARSET’: None, ‘COLLATION’: None, ‘MIGRATE’: True, ‘MIRROR’: None, ‘NAME’: None}}}
```

I also tried the following:

I then declared the new_user as the database owner.

a. with the "\l" I note it was accepted.

Using the connect command, I changed the database connected:

\c new_db
but the new_db still have the postgres user.

b. Altering the "postgres" user role so it cannot login, but remains the active_user so it doesn't fix my needs.

In short, if I want to run migrations in my project, I'm then bound to use the default values for my database, which isn't a good practice.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do so the new_db and new_user created are the ones which are connected to my project db?

Comment: Shouldn't you edit [the Django `DATABASES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATABASES) on your own? It looks like everything works in PostgreSQL but you expect the Django to detect the changes and switch to a new user automatically. Why? If you created 5 new databases and 7 different users, which one would you expect Django to pick as the new default, and based on what?

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek, you are right. I did however, passed the db variables to my django database, I even hardcoded them. The problem though is before. I cannot connect any other databse then the default one. For example, \c new_db raises the error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "new_db" does not exist. Previous connection kept.

Comment: 1) This question is really not about the `postgres` user, it is about creating a database. Change title to indicate that. 2) Best bet is you not creating the new database on the same Postgres instance as you are connecting to. 3) This `'NAME': 'postgres'` needs to be changed to new database name.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible that it is in fact the same cluster but [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) is for some reason preconfigured to only allow local connections, and only to database `postgres`, and `psql` is reporting absence of `new_db` because it fails to connect to it, not because it doesn't exist. That's a wild guess especially since `psql` should be perfectly capable of verifying whether the other db exists without connecting to it. Still, worth a check if the other ideas won't work.

Comment: @Zegarek, that would get you something like: `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5482" failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "db_admin", database "plant_grower_db", no encryption`